# Query concatenated fields in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, concatenation, sequelize.js

I am implementing an application using Sequelize to handle communication with the database.

I have a number of users in the database and I want to implement some search-functionality which allows users to find other users based on their full name. 
A user has (amongst other attributes) a firstName and a lastName in its model.

A user who is looking for another user can search for "John Doe", where John is the first name and Doe is the last name.
Unfortunately, the first name and last name are stored in separate fields in my model. Because of this, I need to concatenate the firstName and lastName field in the "where"-clause as I tried below.

In the where-clause I am just concatenating firstName and lastName and then check whether that is "like" the full name that is passed as the argument `name`. I think the intention of this code below is clear. It is however not working (error says it doesn't expect the '(' after concat so this syntax isn't allowed). Is there an easy trick to do this or should I write my own query using `sequelize.query`?

```
var findUserByName = function(name) {
    return models.User.find({where: {concat(firstName,' ',lastName): like: name}});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This you can try in where clause**

```
where: {
  $and: [
    Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn('concat', Sequelize.col('firstName'), ' ', Sequelize.col('lastName')), {
        like: '%'+name+'%'
      }
    )
  ]
}
```

Comment: please consider adding some hints as how and where to use this code in regards with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that like this:

```
User.find({
    where: {
        $or: [
            name: {
                $like: ['%', firstName, '%'].join('')
            },
            lastName: {
                $like: ['%', lastName, '%'].join('')
            }
        ]
    }).success(function (user) {});
```

Comment: Are you sure this is Sequelize-code? This looks like a MongoDB query to me.

Also: I don't think this would work. Imagine I am looking for the term "ohn Do" who is in the database with "firstName" John, and "lastName" Doe. I don't think your suggested query will return any results because there is no "firstname" or "lastName" that is 'like' "ohn Do". The two should somehow be concatenated.

Comment: It's code in the Sequelize docs - http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#complex-filtering-or-queries so I guess it's Sequelize-code.

Comment: Perhaps including your model definition or table with entries could help, because I can't get your needs without that info